# How to make Spring MVC controller work with UTF-8?

Tags: ajax, jquery, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am using jQuery AJAX to submit a form to a Spring MVC controller in the backed. I am setting encoding on top of the jsp. In my request headers in Firebug I see -

```
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive          115
Connection          keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

However in my Spring MVC controller all the form values entered in Cyrillic turn into junk. And a twist to this is that this works fine in Safari but not in IE/FF/Chrome.

Any thoughts as to how I can set the correct encoding and prevent junk chars from getting submitted?

Comment: Do you have both `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` **and** `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` in your page?

Comment: Yes it was. Still it did not work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. I had set the encoding on top of each jsp page. Yet it was not working. So I added a spring character encoding filter in the web.xml. This will ensure that the encoding is correctly in the request.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: The solution works, very nice. I would like to understand though why it is necessary. All files, JSP page directives, meta tags are set to UTF-8. Why does ISO-8859 pop up in firebug as first option for accept-charset. Weird...

Comment: @Daniel : I faced the same issue. I had also set UTF-8 everywhere. And the twist was that it worked fine in Safari but not in rest of the browsers.

Comment: This solution just saved me from having to work the weekend!!